# TinyMCE 4.2.6 for the English and French users

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Did anyone successfully put 2 editors in different languages on the same page?

When I tried adding one editor in English and another in French, the first editor's top level menu items remained in English, but the drop down menus, tooltips and dialogue buttons all changed to French.

It seems that the last call to `.init` translates not only the ID provided in `selector`, but the other editor except the top level menus as follows:
[image]

This is the config I am using:

```
<textarea id="emailBody" rows="7" name="emailBody"></textarea><br />
<textarea id="emailBodyFrench" name="emailBodyFrench"></textarea><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var oInitBodyEng = {
        selector: "#emailBody",
        language: "en_CA"
    };

    tinymce.init(oInitBodyEng); 

    var oInitBodyFr = {
        selector: "#emailBodyFrench",
        language: "fr_FR"
    };

    tinymce.init(oInitBodyFr);
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I am initializing the 2nd editor that might cause partial translation of the editor already initialized? Does any initialization have to be performed asynchronously?

Comment: I am having same issue, did you found any solution? if yes can you please share it?

Comment: @rkaartikeyan Nope, the developers never even responded to the posts in their support forum. It happened around the time they migrated their issue tracker from their site to github (if I remeber correctly) so you might want to create an issue in the new tracker. Mine was in the old one and I am not sure it was migrated or even looked at. I do not work with TinyMCE anymore, so you will probably have to carry the torch. Sorry!